# How to Json Parsing in android

Tags: android, json

http://docs.blackberry.com/sampledata.json

This is my web service and I want to parse and retrieve vehicleType, vehicleColor, fuel, name, experiencePoints, treadType.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static String url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Tamil%20ndau,Salem&destination=Tamil%20nadu,%20salem&region=in&sensor=false";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        JSONObject json=JSONParser.getJSONfromURL(url);  // here i am able to read content of that web service 
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

Please tell me how can I get the value? I'm not able to pick node for Json object and Json array. Please tell me what I have to do next so that I can retrieve the value. I am new in Json parsing and android. Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May be this code help for you

```
public class JSONfunctions {

public static JSONArray getJSONfromURL(String url) {
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONArray jArray = null;

    // http post
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    // convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag get data string ",
                "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {

        jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag create object ",
                "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jArray;
}
  }
```

This is parsing code example you can change this.

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);

    JSONArray json = JSONfunctions
            .getJSONfromURL("http://docs.blackberry.com/sampledata.json");

    for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

        try {
            Log.e("json names vehicleType", ""
                    + json.getJSONObject(i).getString("vehicleType"));
            Log.e("json names vehicleColor", ""
                    + json.getJSONObject(i).getString("vehicleColor"));
            Log.e("json names fuel",
                    "" + json.getJSONObject(i).getString("fuel"));
            Log.e("json names treadType", ""
                    + json.getJSONObject(i).getString("treadType"));

            Log.e("json names approvedOperators",
                    ""
                            + json.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray(
                                    "approvedOperators"));

            JSONArray array = json.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray(
                    "approvedOperators");
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length(); j++) {

                Log.e("json names approvedOperators name ", ""
                        + array.getJSONObject(j).getString("name"));
                Log.e("json names approvedOperators experience ",
                        ""
                                + array.getJSONObject(j).getString(
                                        "experiencePoints"));

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: I recommend that you DON'T use that `JSONParser class.  It fails abysmally in the case where remote server responds with non-JSON content.  And a few other cases.

Comment: Stephen, please provide an alternative then...I do not understand comments like yours that only criticize, but do not provide answers

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
 HttpGet request = new HttpGet(loginUrl);
 HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
 entityResponse = response.getEntity();
 result = EntityUtils.toString(entityResponse);  


JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("routes"); 


---Parsing first jsonArray     
  JSONObject routes = array.getJSONObject(0);


---(parsing first jsonarray object)
  String bounds= routes.getString("bounds"); 


-- parsing second josn Array  
  JSONArray legs = routes.getJSONArray("legs"); 


--- (parsing second jsonarray object)   

JSONObject steps = legs.getJSONObject(0); 

String distance= routes.getString("distance"); 


--- parsing third json Array
  JSONArray legs1 = steps.getJSONArray("steps"); 
  for(int i = 0; i < legs1.length(); i++){
  JSONObject steps1 = legs1.getJSONObject(i);


--parsing third jsonarray objecct      
  String htMlVale = steps1.getString("html_instructions").toString(); 


-- parsing inside third jsonarray of jsonarray   
  JSONObject distance             =  steps1.getJSONObject("distance");
          String sDistance                =  distance.getString("text");()



        }
}
```

Comment: check this http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2012/02/android-jsonparsing-tutorial.html

Comment: ok if want value copyrights,text,value,lat,lang plz how i will get this value..?

Comment: String distance= routes.getString("distance");  after that break point terminating and excepcetion throing

Answer (score 0):

you can use this class :

just make the object of this class and call the method!!

```
public class JSONParser {


    private static String result;
    private static String resultArr;

    public static String getJSONArr (String json,String tag1,int arrNum)
    {

        try {
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                if(i==arrNum){
                    JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
                resultArr = row.getString(tag1);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return resultArr;

    }

    public static String getJSONObj (String json,String tag1)
    {
        try {
            JSONObject jObj =  new JSONObject(json);

            if(jObj.has(tag1))
                result = jObj.getString(tag1);
            else
                Log.d("JSON ERROR", "tag not found");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: this allredy i did and am able to geting content but i havw parsing an geting all value one by one in string using parsing

Comment: Have u seen the code ... ?? it is not one you will find it on net.. try this once!

Comment: what is the problem now... please elaborate!

Comment: SONArray json = JSONParser.getJSONfromURL(url); ERROR :cannot convert from String to JSONArray

Comment: getJSONfromURL telling crete method in JSONPArse class

Answer (score -1):

The given url returns a JSONArray, so the method getJSONFromUrl should return JSONArray..

```
try {
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, Constants.CONNECTION_TIME_OUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 0);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

        //prepare the HTTP GET call 
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urlString);
        //get the response entity
        HttpEntity entity = httpClient.execute(httpget).getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            //get the response content as a string
            String response = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            //consume the entity
            entity.consumeContent();

            // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed, shut down the connection manager to ensure immediate deallocation of all system resources
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

            //return the JSON response
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.trim());
                for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++) { //get the current JSON object
                    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
                    String vehicleType = object.getString("vehicleType");
                    ......
                 }
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I recommend that you DON'T use that `JSONParser class. It fails abysmally in the case where remote server responds with non-JSON content. And a few other cases.